# Powershell: If user in domain x add to AD group y

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, powershell-3.0

So I have a need to run a script that checks the membership of an AD group. Each member in this AD group will be added to a specific AD group based on the their domain. While this seems fine for a small number of users, I'm looking for a way to do this for +20,000 users regularly.

Example: We have an AD group called NorthAmerica, We want to add members of NorthAmerica into either WestCoast or EastCoast AD groups, based on if their domain is WestCoast, or EastCoast.

```
For users in NorthAmerica
    If user domain in West coast add user to WestCoast AD group
    If user domain in East coast add user to EastCoast AD group
Next
```

How does one do this effeciently? Going through each member of NorthAmerica and adding them one by one doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck at? What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try Add-ADGroupMember which 'adds one or more members to an Active Directory group'.

Try help `Add-ADGroupMember -Detailed` and look as Members to see how to specify them.  I couldn't see a limit but I'd suggest batching them up.